# How to store pdf and show in browser laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have store pdf in storage folder with this code

```
$request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:sliders|max:255',
        'sub_title' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required',
    ]);

    $image = $request->hasFile('file') ? Storage::disk('public')->put('sliders', $request->file('file')) : null;

    $slider = new Slider([
       'title' => $request->get('title'),
       'sub_title' => $request->get('sub_title'),
        'image' => $image
    ]);

    $slider->save();
```

Now how can i show the pdf in browser when click link?

Comment: You can use a `<iframe>` for this with a `url` to pdf.

Comment: try this. Show file does't exist. But file available in my storage folder and database

Answer (score 0):

use `<iframe>` to show pdf in browser . Make sure your path was correct.

```
<iframe src="file.pdf" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: After try this got the console error "jquery.min.js:1251 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined"

take place of pdf, but don't show the pdf

Comment: <iframe src ="{{ asset('storage/',$slider->image) }}" width="1000px" height="600px"></iframe>

File directory storage->app->public->sliders

Comment: <iframe src ="{{ asset('storage/app/public/sliders/',$slider->image) }}" width="1000px" height="600px"></iframe> @Nirob Try this and let me know

Comment: Jubair Mizan look same before

Comment: URL::asset('storage/app/public/sliders/'.$slider->image) make sure you are use dot not comma , before `$slider->image` @Nirob

Comment: @Nirob `{{ URL::asset('storage/app/public/sliders/'.$slider->image) }}` try this

Comment: <iframe src ="{{ URL::asset('storage/'.$slider->image) }}" width="1000px" height="600px"></iframe
Work for me like that, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Nirob If this work for you, then you can upvote this and mark this as answer .

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for generating pdf link from storage and create the route for it, the code should like this :

```
public function displayPDF()
{
    $filepath = 'path_to_pdf.pdf';
    return response()->file(storage_path($file_path));
}
```

ref : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-responses